# The output result is not what I expected

Tags: c++, for-loop, cout

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    const int Map_x = 30, Map_y = 30;

    for (int x = 0; x < Map_x; ++x)
        cout << "■";

    cout << endl;

    for (int y = 0; y < Map_y; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Map_x; ++x)
        {
            if (x == 0 || x == Map_x - 2)
                cout << "■";

            cout << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < Map_x; ++x)
        cout << "■";

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to use "■" character to print a big square, but seems like the right side of the square messed up, I'm pretty sure it's not the UNICODE problem and I think there's no problem with my code as well. After I replaced "■" character with "#", it did print what I expect which is a big square. I don't know why the right side of the square messed up with the "■" character.

my IDE: Visual Studio 2015 Professional
Operating system: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

here are some screenshots:

[When I use "■"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6VwR.jpg)

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2mEf.jpg)

Comment: The squares are probably 2 characters wide, while the prison windows are only 1 character. You probably simply need to print 2 times less squares for the top and bottom. Also, that's not a square!

Comment: Don't you see that these characters are _of different width_?

Comment: The square is wider than the space...

Comment: yeah guys, I noticed that "■" character was defined as "const char[3]" but the "#" character was defined as "const char[2]", but how to fix the space problem tho, thanks!

Comment: Pick a different character. Try ASCII 254 ■ rather than a Unicode character.

Comment: @DavidLively OK I'm trying now

Answer (score 1):

Acutally, "■" is not a char but a string literal. When you try to do `char c = "■";`, then the compiler would give an error as below. Use `strlen(const char *str)` in `#include<cstring>` header to measure its length, then I get 3.

```
1.cpp:7:14: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
     char c = "■";
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick a different character. Try ASCII 254 ■ rather than a Unicode character.

Characters in the fixed-width font used by the  Windows console are NOT square. They're roughly 8x16 including padding. You'd need to approximately double the number of characters for the horizontal axis to get something resembling a square.

[See this link for a more extended character codes.](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Make sure you're using a sane font for cmd.exe, as well.

I modified your source to:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    const int Map_x = 30, Map_y = 30;
    char c = 254;

    for (int x = 0; x < Map_x; ++x)
        cout << c;

    cout << endl;

    for (int y = 0; y < Map_y; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Map_x; ++x)
        {
            if (x == 0 || x == Map_x - 2)
                cout << c;

            cout << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < Map_x; ++x)
        cout << c;

    cout << endl;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

And I get this:

[image]

Comment: ok the output is still the same just like I use the "■" character, should I just copy the character you sent up there or should I add something in my code?

Comment: @BaronZhu Instead of "x", make it a char - single quotes - and you may want to change the code page for your source file back. Want font are you using in cmd.exe? When I run this, I get `?` for everything.

Comment: you mean like this? cout << '■'

Comment: Just do `cout << (char)254;`

Comment: yeah I see your picture there, but it's actually printed a ■ on my console

Comment: @BaronZhu And, yes, that's what I meant by single quotes.

Comment: thank you for being so patient, really appreciate it, I think I need to change my code page and then try your solution out.

Comment: I just uploaded a new picture I found from Google Images, that's actually what I want, no spaces between each line of squares

Comment: @BaronZhu Look at the ascii table (extended chars). There are a few that fully fill the cell, like 219.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote quite a few console games and I believe it's a rule of thumb to **output *2* spaces** at one time:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < Map_x; ++x)
    {
        if (x == 0 || x == Map_x - 2)
            cout << "■";

        cout << "  ";
//               ^^ TWO!
    }
```